# Getting my rank by my time

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get my current position / rank as output in MySQL for my time?

Like

```
SELECT rank (get rank from my time: `time`) FROM entries WHERE member = 'my userid' and quiz_id = '2'
```

My table name is "entries" and the score is "time" (which the lowest is the best score, because it's time. and not highest score)

My columns is id, time, member, quiz_id

I tried searching on Stackoverflow on ranks, but couldn't get a solution, hope something can help me though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This counts your rank for your quiz times only:

```
SELECT count(*)+1 as rank FROM entries 
    WHERE member = 'my userid' and quiz_id = '2' and time < :time;
```

Or your best time in the table compared to other's time:

```
SELECT count(*) as rank from entries
    WHERE quiz_id = '2'and 
        time <= (SELECT time FROM entries 
             WHERE member = 'my userid' and quiz_id = '2');
```

Or if you have multiple times stored for the same (quiz_id,member) pair:

```
SELECT count(*) as rank from 
    (SELECT min(time) as min_time, member, quiz_id 
        FROM entries 
        WHERE time <= (SELECT min(time) FROM entries 
             WHERE member = :user_id and quiz_id = :quiz_id)
                 AND quiz_id=:quiz_id
        GROUP BY quiz_id, member) Q;
```

Select rank compared to time as parameter, if there is only one time per user per quiz...

```
SELECT count(*)+1 as rank FROM entries 
    WHERE quiz_id = '2' and time < :time;
```

and when multiple times are stored for the same member and same quiz:

```
SELECT count(*) as rank from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT member
        FROM entries 
        WHERE time <= :time AND quiz_id = :quiz_id) Q;
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly. SELECT count(*) as rank FROM entries 
    WHERE member = '1' and quiz_id = '1' and time < 5.7180788517 My column "time" is DOUBLE, and is miliseconds. The best time is 2.48445487022 but saying 5.7180788517 is rank 1?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHERE member <> 'my userid'`?

Comment: @user3195288 Yes, I added a count(*)+1. Anyway, I think I misunderstood the question, so added another query.

Comment: Doesn't work, MySQL cannot run that command. #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. Not either in PHP MySQL

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html According to this, the problem does not lie in the query, but in the client code. I actually tried this query, and it works. At least with mysql 5.5

Comment: Do you have multiple time values for the same (member,quiz_id) pair? What mysql version do you use? (though it probably does not matter, subqueries are allowed for quite a long time) Do you use some kind mysql browser (mysql workbench, phpmyadmin)?

Comment: I wanna find my rank for my current time, ex. 9.01150798798, and member = 1 and quiz_id = 1. It has to output "rank" as the rank i am. Think i did ask wrong